# Maven surefire - test failures on clean install

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC project that I am currently working on. Everything looks fine and I am not missing any of the jar files. On "mvn clean install" I am getting the error below.

So far I've tried all the other suggestion that I found on similar topics like: "mvn dependency::tree" so I can check if I am missing any repository but no result. 
For some guys it looks like "mvn clean install -U" was the solution but not in my case, getting the same error.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:17 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-12-09T11:46:34+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/226M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
12.4:test (default-test) on project am: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Code Base\Removable Disk\am
\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Code Base\Removable Disk\am>
```

Comment: you must share the whole stacktrace so it's possible to find out what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

One or more test(s) are failing. You have two options

1. Fix those test cases and try.

   or
2. Run `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip`. This command will skips the test phase.

Comment: I have tried and it will skip indeed the test part, however I am getting another error now.                                  `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:
run (package-frontend-resources) on project am: An Ant BuildException has occure
d: unless=cmdsuccess
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<fail unless="cmdsuccess"/>... @ 14:30 in C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Code Base\Removable Disk\am\target\antrun\build-Building front
end resources.xml`

Comment: Your answer is not accurate. What if the errors happen even though the tests pass running in other ways?

Comment: @ÍcaroErasmo, The error message, is clear that there are tests failure.

Comment: the thing is that tests can be failing because of some defects in dependencies or because some class is not being loaded during test. This answer is not enough

Comment: @ÍcaroErasmo Yes, tests can fail for various reasons. Without a detailed error message, it's difficult to answer a solution. With the given information in the question, I think my answer is still a valid one.